# Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision, objects still collide

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having trouble with the below code, despite the Layer Collision Matrix saying that the layers should not collide (even when set manually), objects marked with layers 8 still collide with objects from layer 11.

Is there a fix/alternative for making objects from different layers not collide.

```
if (Drop)
{
    Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision(11, 8);
}
else
{
     Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision(11, 8, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.

Disabled `Use Collider Mask` on `Platform Effector 2D` in my Prefab

and changed the code to:

```
      if (Drop)
        {
            Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision(8, 11);

            myGameObject.GetComponent<EdgeCollider2D>().enabled = false;
            myGameObject.GetComponent<EdgeCollider2D>().enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision(8, 11, false);
        }
```